# Puppet Install Visual Studio Every Single Run

Tags: windows, puppet

I want to install Visual studio using puppet but on every single puppet run, the setup installs VS over and over again.

```
package { 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2012':
       ensure => installed,
       source => '\\goliath\Users\DanishKhakwani\VisualStudio\Premium\vs_premium.exe',
       install_options => ['/SILENT', '/FULL'],
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the software listing entry is exactly `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012`?

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/puppet-community/puppet-visualstudio module.

Comment: One can also use the chocolatey provider - https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey#why-chocolatey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the [package name exactly matches the display name](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.6/reference/resources_package_windows.html#package-name-must-be-the-displayname) of Visual Studio.

For posterity:

> The title (or name) of the package must match the value of the package’s DisplayName property in the registry, which is also the value displayed in the “Add/Remove Programs” or “Programs and Features” control panel.
>
> If the provided name and the installed name don’t match, Puppet will believe the package is not installed and try to install it again.

Comment: This is exactly what I was coming here to mention. +1

Comment: Do you mind if I add to your answer to state using Chocolatey as an alternative doesn't have the same issues?

Comment: thanks, Chris! <br/>
@ferventcoder I am aware of Choco but the thing is, the setup that I am using doesn't require me to enter a license key and it is already licensed.

Comment: Danish - if you use choco, you can still create your own package that does the same - let's not equate choco abilities to what a particular package may or may not do. Many folks using puppet and choco maintain their own internal packages and an internal repo - which stands up easily with https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey_server

Comment: @ferventcoder Thanks! I will look into hosting my own packages using choco server. :)